# How install 7 zip on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I using python script for make zip files using 7zip on windows

But not in Heroku.. in Heroku i must install 7zip app.how i do that using `sudo`

I use `apt-get install 7zip-full` on heroku bash. but below is my return error:

`$ apt-get install p7zip-full
apt-get install p7zip-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to locate package p7zip-full`

Now my question is:

How install 7zip on heroku?

Comment: How are you using 7-zip? Shelling out probably isn't the most efficient way of doing that, and there are probably Python libraries that let you work with such files without having a `7za` binary available.

Comment: In any case, you can't use `apt` (or anything similar) on Heroku. Your dependencies must be declared as part of your application, e.g. in a `requirements.txt` file, and / or provided by a buildpack.

Comment: @Chris I se subprocess.call like `rc = subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', '-mx=9','-t7z', zip_file_pw, '-mhe', '-y', OutPutArchive] + [filename])`

Comment: @Chris I  want a pasword protected zip file...but unforgettably this can't be done by usual library... ....can i make archive with password using internal Python library?

Comment: Not with the built-in one, but it looks like there are [other options](https://pypi.org/project/pyminizip/). If you still want to use 7-zip you can try [adding](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) one that [installs 7-zip](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/opendoor-labs/heroku-buildpack-p7zip).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use 7zip on Heroku 
here build-pack of 7zip

**https://github.com/opendoor-labs/heroku-buildpack-p7zip**

use this official Heroku guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks to know how to add buildpacks or simply use following command

**heroku buildpacks:set   < buildpack-url > -a < app-name >**

Buildpack: url is simply github url of your buildpack  to you or any other also it can be official build pack name

App-name refer to name u given to app

also you can use following if you don't want to use commandline

go to dashboard -> select your app -> scroll down until you see buildpack section with add buildpack button enter the given 7zip buildpack GitHub link and done

also there alternative 7zip for python3 [py7zr](https://pypi.org/project/py7zr/)

Comment: Because there's a possibility the Heroku link might one day go down, in your answer, it is best to provide a summary of the command line steps to take

Comment: even heroku change site i provided alternative methods so no worry , still i updated mt answer